# Ubercart hook_order and delete

Tags: 7, ubercart

So I am wanting to execute some code when an order is deleted in Ubercart. In order to test hooks, I have the following code:

```
function loaner_uc_order ($op, &$arg1, $arg2) {

  if ($op == 'delete') {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO {testing} (text) VALUES ('you deleted order number')";
    db_query($sql);
  }

}
```

The problem is it is just not firing. Am I doing this right? I know the query works because I copy/pasted it into a separate area, and it worked fine. I am honestly stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is [ubercart hook order](http://api.ubercart.me/api/drupal/ubercart!uc_order!uc_order.api.php/function/hook_uc_order/7)

```
hook_uc_order($op, $order, $arg2)
```

**Clear your site cache** from performance page, The hook is fired for me after clearing the cache.

Comment: Omg... that worked. Stuff like that is so frustrating, but live and learn. Thanks again.